# How to distribute a value inside a dataframe rowwise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I did portfolio optimization in Python. I have dataframe with results.

```
Column_names = ['Asset_1', 'Asset_2', 'Asset_3', 'Asset_4', 'Asset_5', 'Asset_6',
       'Asset_7', 'Asset_8', 'Asset_9', 'Asset_10']

List_values = [[0.1 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.55],
       [0.1 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.02, 0.1 , 0.01, 0.02, 0.73, 0.02, 0.  ],
       [0.1 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.03, 0.1 , 0.02, 0.25, 0.  , 0.25, 0.25],
       [0.1 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.04, 0.  , 0.01, 0.  , 0.85, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.1 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.05, 0.  , 0.01, 0.  , 0.84, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.1 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.06, 0.  , 0.01, 0.6 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.23],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.07, 0.  , 0.01, 0.6 , 0.  , 0.32, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.08, 0.  , 0.01, 0.  , 0.  , 0.6 , 0.31],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.09, 0.  , 0.01, 0.  , 0.6 , 0.  , 0.3 ]]

pd.DataFrame(data = List_values, columns = Column_names)
```

The sum of the values in each row is 1. However, the shares are different.

I have a dataframe with limits for each asset:

```
Asset_1 Asset_2 Asset_3 Asset_4 Asset_5 Asset_6 Asset_7 Asset_8 Asset_9 Asset_10
  0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.1     0.3     0.45    0.15    0.3
```

I need to tidy up the dataframe based on the limits that are in the limits dataframe. If the share is larger, then the excess needs to be distributed among those that are as close as possible to the limits.

Then after that do a lower bound check and distribute the remainder if there is one. I have that code in R, but I'd like to use python for that task.

Desired dataframe:

```
**List_values** = [[1.  , 0.08, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.45, 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.15, 0.  ],
       [2.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.07, 0.  , 0.45, 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.15, 0.  ],
       [3.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.07, 0.  , 0.45, 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.15, 0.  ],
       [4.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.07, 0.  , 0.45, 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.15, 0.  ],
       [5.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.07, 0.  , 0.45, 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.15, 0.  ],
       [6.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.09, 0.  , 0.44, 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.15, 0.  ],
       [7.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.1 , 0.  , 0.43, 0.  , 0.  , 0.3 , 0.15, 0.  ]]

**Column_names** = ['Asset_1', 'Asset_2', 'Asset_3', 'Asset_4', 'Asset_5', 'Asset_6',
       'Asset_7', 'Asset_8', 'Asset_9', 'Asset_10']

Desires_DF = (data = List_values, columns = Column_names)
```

R code

```
mpShareDistrib <- function(x, l = 1, m = 1, dtz = F){

  # 0. Check inputs
  ss <- as.numeric(x)
  names(ss) <- names(x)
  ss <- na.omit(ss)

  l <- as.numeric(l)

  if(length(l) == 1) l <- rep(l, times = length(ss))
  if(length(l) != length(ss)) stop('Shares and limit vectors are not equal')

  m <- as.numeric(m)

  if(is.null(names(ss))) names(ss) <- paste0('sec', 1:length(ss))
  if(is.null(names(l))) names(l) <- names(ss)
  if(length(setdiff(names(ss), names(l))) > 0)
    stop('Shares and limit have different names for:', setdiff(names(ss), names(l)) )

  Cut_Share <- function(x, l, m){

    ss1 <- x

    ss1 <- ss1[order(names(ss1))]
    l1  <- l[names(ss1)]

    i <- 1
    while(max(ss1-l1)>0 & i < 10){

      # (above limit stock shares)
      abv_ss <- ss1[ss1>0] - l1[ss1>0]
      abv_ss <- abv_ss[abv_ss > 0]
      abv_ss <- sum(abv_ss)

      new1_ss <- ss1[which((ss1 - l1)>0)]
      new1_l  <- l[names(new1_ss)]
      new1_ss <- new1_ss - (new1_ss - new1_l)

      # (free stock stares)
      free_ss <- ss1[ss1 < l1]

      # (filled stock shares)
      fld_ss <- free_ss + abv_ss * free_ss / sum(free_ss)

 
      new1_ss <- c(new1_ss, ss1[ss1 == l1], fld_ss)

      ss1 <- new1_ss
      ss1 <- round(ss1, digits = 4)
      ss1 <- ss1[order(names(ss1))]

      i <- i + 1
    }

    return(ss1)
  }

  ss1 <- Cut_Share(ss[ss>0], l, m)

  ss2 <- ss1[ss1 > 0]  
  l2  <- l[names(ss2)]

  ss2 <- ss2[order(names(ss2))]
  l2  <- l2[order(names(l2))]

  i <- 1

  while(min(ss2) < m & i < 10){

    min_ss <- ss2[which.min(ss2)]

    free_ss2 <- ss2[-which.min(ss2)]
    free_l2 <- l2[names(free_ss2)]

    free_ss2 <- free_ss2[free_ss2 < free_l2]

    if(length(free_ss2) > 0)
    {

      free_l2 <- free_l2[names(free_ss2)]

      dstr <- free_ss2 / sum(free_ss2) * min_ss

      fld_ss  <- pmin(free_ss2 + dstr, free_l2)

      rem <- min_ss - sum(fld_ss - free_ss2)
      rem <- round(rem, digits = 4)
      names(rem) <- names(min_ss)

      if(rem > 0)
        new2_ss <- c(ss2[ss2 >= l2], fld_ss, rem)
      else
        new2_ss <- c(ss2[ss2 >= l2], fld_ss)

    } else {

      warning('Cannot distribute small share - no free space ')
      break()
    }

    ss2 <- new2_ss
    l2  <- l2[names(new2_ss)]
    i <- i + 1

  }

  # 3. Cut shares above limit
  #
  ss3 <- ss2

  # 4. Finalization
  #
  # Add distributed share with zero value
  {
    lngth_diff <- length(ss) - length(ss3)

    ss0 <- c()
    if(lngth_diff > 0){

      ss0 <- rep(0, lngth_diff)

      rmvd_ss <- setdiff(names(ss), names(ss3))
      names(ss0) <- rmvd_ss
    }

    ss_fin <- c(ss0, ss3)
    ss_fin <- ss_fin[order(names(ss_fin))]

    if(is.null(names(ss))) names(ss_fin) <- NULL

  }

  if(sum(ss) != sum(ss_fin)) warning('Shares distribution error')

  return(ss_fin)

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*I have separate row with limits on each asset.*"? Another DataFrame? Can you also clarify the logic and eventually provide your R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your details about the change from above matrix to matrix below. But i use my way to adjust the values of the DataFrame based on the limits and perform a lower bound check, redistributing the remainder if necessary:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Input data
column_names = ['Asset_1', 'Asset_2', 'Asset_3', 'Asset_4', 'Asset_5', 'Asset_6', 'Asset_7', 'Asset_8', 'Asset_9', 'Asset_10']
list_values = np.array([[0.1, 0., 0., 0., 0.3, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.55],
                        [0.1, 0., 0., 0.02, 0.1, 0.01, 0.02, 0.73, 0.02, 0.],
                        [0.1, 0., 0., 0.03, 0.1, 0.02, 0.25, 0., 0.25, 0.25],
                        [0.1, 0., 0., 0.04, 0., 0.01, 0., 0.85, 0., 0.],
                        [0.1, 0., 0., 0.05, 0., 0.01, 0., 0.84, 0., 0.],
                        [0.1, 0., 0., 0.06, 0., 0.01, 0.6, 0., 0., 0.23],
                        [0., 0., 0., 0.07, 0., 0.01, 0.6, 0., 0.32, 0.],
                        [0., 0., 0., 0.08, 0., 0.01, 0., 0., 0.6, 0.31],
                        [0., 0., 0., 0.09, 0., 0.01, 0., 0.6, 0., 0.3]])

limits_values = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.45, 0.15, 0.3]

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list_values, columns=column_names)

# Adjust values to meet the limits
for i in range(len(df)):
    excess = df.loc[i] - limits_values
    df.loc[i] -= excess[excess > 0].sum() * (df.loc[i] / df.loc[i].sum())

# Lower bound check and distribute remainder
lower_bound = 0.01  # You can adjust the lower bound value as needed
remainder = df[df < lower_bound].sum(axis=1) - lower_bound

for i in range(len(df)):
    mask = df.iloc[i] < lower_bound
    df.loc[i, mask] += remainder[i] * (df.loc[i] / df.loc[i].sum())

# Print the result
print(df.round(2))
```

maybe can give an inspiration.

Comment: I probably need to clarify that the shares should not be greater than the limits, with no less than the lower limit (here, by the way, your decision is top). In this case, it is important for me that the sum of the shares in the line is equal to 1.